# Show that $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent from joint density.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, independence, density-function

I have a random vector $X,Y$ (with respect to the Lebesgue measure):

$$f_{X,Y}=1/2 \mathbb I _{|x|+|y|\leq1}$$

And I want to show that $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent. One way to show it, is to show that:

$$f_{X+Y}f_{X-Y}=f_{X+Y,X-Y}$$

I understand that I can calculate the densities for $X+Y$, $X-Y$ with the usual convolution formula. Although maybe there is the better way... in any case how do I get the joint density?

Comment: Try a change of variables $(X,Y)\to (U,V)$ such that $U=X+Y,V=X-Y$. Find the joint density of $(U,V)$ and from there conclude about independence of $U$ and $V$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $|x|+|y| \leq 1$ if and only if $-1 \leq x+y \leq 1$ and $-1 \leq x-y \leq 1$, and so,

$$ \mathbf{1}_{\{|x|+|y|\leq 1\}} = \mathbf{1}_{\{x+y \in [-1,1]\}} \mathbf{1}_{\{x-y \in [-1,1]\}}. $$

This already tells that the joint density of $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ must split. Indeed, the change of variables $(u, v) = (x+y, x-y)$ shows

\begin{align*}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)\, dxdy
&= \frac{1}{4} \mathbf{1}_{\{u\in [-1,1]\}} \mathbf{1}_{\{v\in [-1,1]\}} \, dudv.
\end{align*}

Therefore the joint density of $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ splits and they are independent.

Comment: You mean $f_{U,V}(u,v)\,du\,dv=...$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom, No, the above formula is exactly what I meant. Any probability regarding $X$ and $Y$ should be computed using $f_{X,Y}$, for instance, $$\mathbb{P}(X+Y \in A, X-Y \in B) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \mathbf{1}_{\{x+y\in A\}} \mathbf{1}_{\{x-y\in B\}} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dxdy $$ for any Borel sets $A$ and $B$, and essentially what I showed is that this equals $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{1}{4} \mathbf{1}_{\{u\in A\cap[-1,1]\}} \mathbf{1}_{\{v\in B \cap[-1,1]\}} \, du dv $$

Comment: I misunderstood. Thanks.

Comment: @StubbornAtom No worries :)

Comment: @SangchulLee May I ask, where did you get the quarter?

Comment: @Dole, One $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from the normalizing constant of $f_{X,Y}$ itself. Another $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from the fact that $dxdy = \frac{1}{2}dudv$, which is essentially the Jacobian.